# IdentityServer 3 and navigating between multiple web applications on same/different domains

Tags: authentication, owin, openid, identityserver3, openid-connect

Question

I am pretty sure my question is not directly related to IdentityServer’s features, but I hope you, guys, can give me an advice to help with next issue. In our environment, we have several web applications running on different domains/machines, which are using IdentityServer as an authentication authority. Everything is working just fine in terms of authentication and authorization and with SSO users can get access to all apps.

This is a problem:

*User navigates for the first time on, let’s say, WebApp1 (http://domain1/WebApp1) which requires authentication – user automatically redirected to IdSrv login. Users enters credentials and then redirects back to WebApp1. Everything is working fine, base “.AspNet.Cookies” –cookie is created and user can navigate within WebApp1 resources without concerns. After wile users navigates to WebApp2 on the same domain (http://domain1/WebApp2). During navigation app makes roundtrip to IdSrv making sure that user is authenticated and returns to WebApp2 (no new login required) – this is ok. But then, if user wants to go back to WebApp1, the new roundtrip to IdSrv is occurred and that is what I want to avoid! And this happends each time user switches between apps.*

Is there any way to prevent those IdSrv roundtrips on every navigation between multiple WebApplication on same/different domains? One workaround I found is to use different names for ASP.NET cookies for each applications, but this makes identity sign-out way more complicated.

Also got advice from @brockallen to use diffent cookie name for each separate webapp, but what about single sign out? Once logging out on WebApp1, WebApp2 still remains logged in until new roundtrip to IdScrv will ooccur or cookie exp

Comment: did you ever figure out a solution?